# find the Power without loop or recursive call

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Hi Stack overflow community recently came across this question..
where the interviewer asked me to find the power of the given number without any loop or recursive call no inbuilt.

Example :2^3 = 8  , 3 ^ 3 = 27

please let me know if there is a ans :)

### My approach was

```
int val = 2;
int pow = 3;
while (pow != 0)
{
result *= val;
--pow;
}
```

Comment: If the base is 2 you need only to bitwise left shift the amount of power. bitwise left shift is like multiplying by 2.

Comment: Can always just use `Math.pow(double a, double b)` https://www.baeldung.com/java-math-pow

Comment: no inbuilt methods too and it can be any number, 2 , 3 , 6 any

Comment: "without any loop or recursive call no inbuilt" .. that leaves approximately nothing. Unrolled loop maybe, but that's basically a loop that we're not writing as a loop - a cheat.

Comment: is this a java specific question expecting you to solve it using a java feature/library or is it some general technique like bit manipulation?